# gmap4rails not displaying map unless jquery not called

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have a really weird problem using gmap4rails.  I followed the setup on github exactly and I just get a blank box.  I can see that there are calls being made to the map provider (in this case, Bing), but no map is never rendered.

In profiling the javascript, the Gmap4rails code is never executed.

My view looks like this:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @map},
"map_options" => { "zoom" => 15, "provider" => "bing", "provider_key" => ENV['BING_MAPS_API_KEY'], "auto_adjust" => true }) %>
```

Javascript embeded in the page via "<%= yield :scripts %>" (I removed my API key here, but it's there on my page):

```
<script src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsBing();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.zoom = 15;
Gmaps.map.map_options.provider = "bing";
Gmaps.map.map_options.provider_key = "<key here>";
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lat":39.45000076293945,"lng":-98.90799713134766}];
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
Gmaps.oldOnload = window.onload;
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
</script>
```

If I remove jquery from my js manifest, the map is displayed and the gmap4rails javascript is executed.  (I only found this out by accident because I was using jquery-rails-cdn and thought it may be conflicting so I removed it, without re-adding jquery to the manifest).

I think it may have something to do with the onload call, perhaps it should be a ready call instead?

I should also mention that I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.  I did already add the css modifications as recommended, and required the file via sass.

css looks like this:

```
#map img { 
  max-width: none;
}
#map label { 
  width: auto; display:inline; 
}

.map_container {
  padding: 6px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
  width: 800px;
}

.gmaps4rails_map {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}

.bing_map {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20;
   left: 10;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   border:#555555 2px solid;
}
```

The ultimate goal is to have the map within a bootstrap tab-pane (probably another headache), but right now I'm just trying to get it to display on the page at all.

I'd would really appreciate any help from the community--been bashing my head on the keyboard with this one for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the wierdness with jquery, I suspected some type of collision with the onload (it might also be bootstrap instead).

I cannot use the <%= yield :scripts %> directly, but if I copy the generated code and paste it in, modifying the onload calls to the jquery native handlers as follows everything works.

```
<div class="map_container">
    <div id="map" class="bing_map"></div>
</div>
<script src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsBing();
    Gmaps.load_map = function() {
    Gmaps.map.map_options.provider = "bing";
    Gmaps.map.map_options.provider_key = "<key here>";
    Gmaps.map.map_options.autozoom = false;
    Gmaps.map.map_options.zoom = 15;
    Gmaps.map.initialize();
    Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lat":30.40438547730446,"lng":-86.61866784095764}];
    Gmaps.map.create_markers();
    Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
    Gmaps.map.callback();
    };
    Gmaps.oldOnload = $(window).load();
    $(window).load(function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); });
</script>
```